# C# How to label an image dataset

Tags: c#, classification, ml.net

I'm attempting to do binary image classification using ML.NET.

I have a dataset of malaria samples, which are split into two classes/categories: "Parasitized" and "Uninfected" and contains 27,000 images in each class.

The two classes/categories are separated into two folders already.

Is it possible to iterate through all of the images in the first folder and add the image file names and the label 0 then save it to a .csv file, then repeat the same process for the second folder but give them the label 1.

Then when it is training, it will be able to use the .csv file for reference to know which class each image belongs to, by using the corresponding image name and label. But I'm not sure whether it is possible to extract the file name of an image, then save it to file?

Perhaps I'm approaching this in the wrong way and/or misunderstanding how labeling data should work. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be really appreciated!

Comment: If you have already organised the samples into 2 different folders, one for _"Parasitized"_ and another for _"Uninfected"_, why do you need the CSV to tell it what classification a sample belongs to?  Can't you just gleam it from whichever folder the image resides in?

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification-api-transfer-learning